# Child windows docking in MDI forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an MDI form and some child forms within. I dock the child forms to different areas of MDI window, but when any of the child forms loses focus, the other docked forms will rearrange. Because of the confusion I prepared a set of images to show the behavior.

Image1, Before clicking on any window:

[image]

Image2, After clicking on window 2:

[image]

The problem is when the most left hand side docked form gets the focus, it'll resize to the right end of MDI window without accounting for window 1.

How can I fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: MDI and docking are antipodes, the windowing model strongly favors overlapped children.  Made a lot of sense 20 years ago when users had 640 x 480 resolution monitors.  Use a docking library like http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/

Comment: I know it's not the right way to do this but I wanted to try. I worked with dockpanelsuit, It's great but I'm more comfortable with my own stuff. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Better yet, stop using MDI. As Hans says, it's not designed for docking and it's going to fight you all the way. If you want to invent your own wheel, it'll be much easier if you drop the MDI style and just use regular docking children.

Comment: @Cody Gray - I did what you said with usercontrols. They are fine but It's a lot easier to implement these kinds of things with Windows forms. DockPanelSuite inherited the windows forms class for its float panels, I think it's the true way.

Comment: I don't understand what that has to do with MDI, the multiple document interface. WinForms supports MDI and non-MDI interfaces.

Comment: I want to show multiple forms in a MDI like the visual studio itself but VS uses its own way, next I want to give some of my forms the ability of docking. Thanks for ya'all helps, I'll try to choose another way.

Answer (score 2):

There's another fix for this. A very fast example would be:

- Create a new windows form (Form1). Set its isMidiContainer property to true.
- Now, drop a panel (Panel1) on it and set its dock property to right, and then set your width.
- Drop another panel (panel2) on the form and set its dock to right as well. Now these two panels docks next to each other.

Now create 2 new windows forms (Form 2 and Form3).

Now, in Form1's main, just underneath InitializeComponent(), add:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.TopLevel = false;
f2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
panel1.Controls.Add(f2);
f2.Show();

Form3 f3 = new Form3();
f3.TopLevel = false;
f3.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
panel2.Controls.Add(f3);
f3.Show();
```

This is a little different approach but it should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for reply after this long time. I studied about `Form.TopLevel` earlier this month and this question is solved.

Comment: Cool beans. Now others can see if they have the same problem:).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried fixing the size youself on the Resize method of the child form (W2)?

```
    //something like this
    private void W2_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Size pSize = this.ClientSize;
        // Resize the form
    }
```

Or meybe use the Focus method.
I don't know if it would cause perfomence issues though.

Comment: I didn't but I think it would stay on the previous style. I'll give  a try.